# Merge objects from a second file to each object on first file

Tags: yaml, yq

I have following `master.yaml` file

```yaml
root:
  - name: First
    some_value: One
  - name: Second
    some_value: Two
```

and `update.yaml` file

```yaml
defaults:
  other_value: true
  one_more: Three
```

The expected result is:

```yaml
root:
  - name: First
    some_value: One
    other_value: true
    one_more: Three
  - name: Second
    some_value: Two
    other_value: true
    one_more: Three
```

I tried following command:

`yq eval-all '(select(fileIndex == 0).root.[] *+ select(fileIndex == 1).defaults)' './master.yaml' './update.yaml'`

but the result is:

```yaml
name: First
some_value: One
other_value: true
one_more: Three
name: Second
some_value: Two
other_value: true
one_more: Three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`load` function](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-two-files-together) also to merge the second file against the first. i.e.

```
yq '.root[] *= load("update.yaml").defaults' master.yaml
```

OP seems to be running `yq` on Windows/Powershell. There is an additional layer of quotes needed to execute command-line programs on it. See [Quotes on Windows Powershell](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/tips-and-tricks#quotes-in-windows-powershell)

Comment: every time I'm using load function I have flowing error: `Error: parsing expression: Lexer error: could not match text starting at 1:17 failing at 1:20.
        unmatched text: "upd"`

Comment: What version of `yq` are you running? It worked fine for me on the current latest (v4.25.3). Also are you running it exactly like I've shown in the answer?

Comment: yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.25.1
running exactly answer

Comment: Can you upgrade and try?

Comment: this is the latest version for windows: https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/yq

Comment: Take it from the Github releases page - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.25.3

Comment: Exactly the same error

Comment: In general, there is a quoting mess associated with windows, you might need to 2 x double quote. See https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/747 or https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/tips-and-tricks#quotes-in-windows-powershell

Comment: All working. Any tip for adding only new values but keep existing?

Comment: @Marcin Please ask a separate question for the same

Comment: done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72810898/set-default-values-for-defined-keys-in-yaml-but-keep-existsing-values