# Deep merge two YAML files and keep only new fields

Tags: yaml, yq

I have following `master.yaml` file

```yaml
root:
  - name: First
    some_value: One
    one_more: Four
    elements:
      first: e
  - name: Second
    some_value: Two
    elements:
      first: a
      second: b
```

and `update.yaml` file

```yaml
defaults:
  other_value: true
  one_more: Three
  elements:
      first: a
      second: b
      third: c
```

The expected result is:

```yaml
root:
  - name: First
    some_value: One
    other_value: true
    one_more: Four
    elements:
      first: e
      second: b
      third: c
  - name: Second
    some_value: Two
    other_value: true
    one_more: Three
    elements:
      first: a
      second: b
      third: c
```

I have already following query:
 `yq '.root[] *= load(\""update.yaml\"").defaults' master.yaml`

but it replaces existing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mikeafarh/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) supports [merging only new fields](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-only-new-fields), so that the existing ones are not modified

```
yq '.root[] *=n load("update.yaml").defaults' master.yaml
```

Comment: Thx, I tried `*n=` and failed

Comment: seems no longer working in yq 4.27.3

Comment: @Marcin If it worked on earlier version and not in the newer, I would suggest raise a bug report on the tool. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's `*=n`, not `*n=`, although I found the `n` to be weird.

This worked for me to merge several files. Note that it will not merge arrays - it will overwrite them.

```
$ echo '' > result.yaml; for f in global.yaml dev.yaml tenant1.yaml; do echo -e "\n# $f"; cat $f; yq -i ". *= load(\"$f\")" result.yaml; done; echo -e "\n# result.yaml"; cat result.yaml; echo

# global.yaml
ingress:
  enabled: false
  hostname: example.com
env:
  - DB_USER: postgres
  - DB_DATABASE: example

# dev.yaml
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hostname: dev.example.com
env:
  - DB_USER: postgres
  - DB_DATABASE: example-dev
  - ENVIRONMENT: dev

# tenant1.yaml
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hostname: tenant1.example.com
env:
  - DB_DATABASE: tenant1-dev
billing_enabled: true

# result.yaml
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hostname: tenant1.example.com
env:
  - DB_DATABASE: tenant1-dev
billing_enabled: true

[evans@evans test]$
```